# What happened to the Help->Index menu item in VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I've been using VS2010RC and I really miss the old help system. Is it coming back in the release version? Is this the way help will be in VisualStudio for the foreseeable future?

I miss incremental search more than anything else. Although I also miss independent scrolling of the help table of contents and the help content.

I also must admit that I can never find it in the taskbar since it is now just one tab of many in my browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Brian Harry's blog, there's going to be an add-on to put the help > index command back in sometime after RTM: http://blogs.msdn.com/bharry/archive/2010/01/25/help-with-help.aspx (see item #5).

Brian has another post two days later talking about help and addressing some more feedback (I can't post a hyperlink because I'm a new user, but it should be relatively straightforward to find).

Comment: @Jeff - thanks. I think this might be the other link you mention http://blogs.msdn.com/bharry/archive/2010/01/27/playing-back-the-help-feedback.aspx